# Incorrect Parameters population in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, hana, ssrs-2017

My report has multiple parameters where the data populated in the dropdown does not show proper data. My parameter is suppose to populate 3 values(`Say A`, `B`, `All`). My parameters are populating just the `ALL` value in the drop down.
I have checked the query in the HANA Studio and the query is absolutely fine and gives A, B and All in the output but the same wont work in SSRS.

- SSRS Version: 2017
- Data Source : SAP HANA

The parameter works absolutely fine in the dev environment but gives the above mentioned issues in other environment.
How can I get all the 3 values in the parameter drop down?

Comment: It sounds like your other environments don't have the data populated for A and B. Can you run the query against the other environments?

Comment: I ran the query on the HANA Studio on all the environments and the output is what I want but the SSRS Parameter wont give the drop down with proper data.

Comment: Make sure your SSRS data source has the correct credentials to the production server.

Comment: It does. Tested the connection.

Comment: Is the data source a shared data source? Is the dataset that fills the parameter dropdown a shared dataset? Verify the settings of the deployed report in "Report Server Portal".

Comment: @Priyanka2304, in the development environment, SSRS will sometimes cache the report data. Try deleting the `.data` file in the report folder solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the expression in your Query parameter when you are dealing with multi value parameters:

```
join(Parameters!<your param name>.Value,",")
```